# Emacs Evil: Invalid function: evil-ensure-column

Tags: evil

I am using `evil` in Emacs, and I get an error when I use the motions `G` or `gg`: `Invalid function: evil-ensure-column`. My Emacs version is 29.1, and the `evil` version is 20230919.2206. The motion `G` calls `evil-goto-line`:

```
(evil-define-motion evil-goto-line (count)
  "Go to line COUNT. By default the last line."
  :jump t
  :type line
  (evil-ensure-column
    (if (null count)
        (goto-char (point-max))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (forward-line (1- count)))))
```

The function that Emacs is complaining about is `evil-ensure-column`:

```
(defmacro evil-ensure-column (&rest body)
  "Execute BODY so that column after execution is correct.
If `evil-start-of-line' is nil, treat BODY as if it were a `next-line' command.
This mostly copies the approach of Emacs' `line-move-1', but is modified
so it is more compatible with Evil's notion of EOL tracking."
  (declare (indent defun) (debug t))
  `(progn
     (unless evil-start-of-line
       (setq this-command 'next-line
             temporary-goal-column
             (cond ((memq last-command '(next-line previous-line))
                    temporary-goal-column)
                   ((and track-eol (eolp) (not (bolp))) most-positive-fixnum)
                   (t (current-column)))))
     ,@body
     (if evil-start-of-line
         (evil-first-non-blank)
       (line-move-to-column
        (or goal-column
            (if (consp temporary-goal-column)
                ;; Guard against a negative value as `temporary-goal-column'
                ;; may have a negative component when both `whitespace-mode'
                ;; and `display-line-numbers-mode' are enabled (#1297).
                (max 0 (+ (truncate (car temporary-goal-column))
                          (cdr temporary-goal-column)))
              temporary-goal-column))))))
```

Running `(evil-goto-line)` gives the trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function evil-ensure-column)
  evil-ensure-column(202876)
  evil-goto-line()
  eval((evil-goto-line) t)
  eval-expression((evil-goto-line) nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression (evil-goto-line) nil nil 127)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression
```

What could be causing this error? I have another system with almost the exact same setup and the keybinds are working fine there.

Comment: Do not post functions content; instead, more helpful, show your configuration. Do you set some variables before calling ```evil``` package?